# Struct Causing Compile Error in C++ Class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct

I am getting errors compiling a C++ class, it relates to a Struct which is to be returned from a method. I have striped the code down to the minimum and still get the errors. I am using Visual Studio 6.0.

Code

```
// TestClass.cpp: implementation of the TestClass class.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestClass.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Construction/Destruction
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

TestClass::TestClass()
{

}

TestClass::~TestClass()
{

}

ProductInfo TestClass::GetProdInfo()
{
    ProductInfo PI;

    return PI;
}

// TestClass.h: interface for the TestClass class.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#if !defined(AFX_TestClass_H__081E411D_44F9_4E0B_9FE7_CF6F708BE769__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_TestClass_H__081E411D_44F9_4E0B_9FE7_CF6F708BE769__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

class TestClass  
{
public:
    struct ProductInfo
    {
        char    cCode;
        char    cItem[20];
        long    lValue;
    };

public:
    TestClass();
    virtual ~TestClass();

private:
    ProductInfo GetProdInfo();
};

#endif // !defined(AFX_TestClass_H__081E411D_44F9_4E0B_9FE7_CF6F708BE769__INCLUDED_)
```

Errors received

```
Compiling...
TestClass.cpp
C:\Work\TestStruct\TestClass.cpp(22) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'tag::id'
C:\Work\TestStruct\TestClass.cpp(22) : error C2501: 'ProductInfo' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
C:\Work\TestStruct\TestClass.cpp(22) : fatal error C1004: unexpected end of file found
Error executing cl.exe.

TestStruct.exe - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Any ideas why i am getting these errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProductInfo` is a nested class in `TestClass`  so you must keep the namespace here.

```
TestClass::ProductInfo TestClass::GetProdInfo()
```

The standard says:

> **9.7 Nested class declarations**
>
> If class *X* is defined in a namespace scope, a nested class *Y* may be
> declared in class X and later defined in the definition of class X or
> be later defined in a namespace scope enclosing the definition of
> class X.
>
> **7.3.1 Namespace definition**
>
> The enclosing namespaces of a declaration are those namespaces in which the declaration lexically appears,
> except for a redeclaration of a namespace member outside its original namespace (e.g., a definition as
> specified in 7.3.1.2). Such a redeclaration has the same enclosing namespaces as the original declaration.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks mate. I knew i was missing something simple.

Comment: Done, was waiting the required 5 mins before accepting

Answer (score 0):

You must either un-nest your struct or change the return type of `GetProdInfo`

```
TestClass::ProductInfo TestClass::GetProdInfo()
{
    ProductInfo PI;

    return PI;
}
```